# Regex: return false if 3 symbols +-* are followed by each other

Tags: java, android, regex

I hope to get help in Regex. I guess it shouldn't be so complex for people who are familiar with Regex. 
We have a text where these 3 symbols +-* cannot be followed with each other. For example Regex should return false if a text contains:

- -t2ext`++`text
- +text`+-`text
- t*ext`+*`text
- t5e-xt`--`text
- te-xt`-+`text
- t5ex-t`-*`tex-t
- te5xt`**`text
- t8ext`*-`te9xt
- te77*xt`*+`te*xt

I tried to solve using negation `^`, but couldn't find a proper solution. I was getting  `Catastrophic Backtracking` error. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Can't you just try to match `[+-*]{2,}` and reject if it actually matches?

Comment: Great @SebastianProske, it is so simple. I would upvote if you wrote it even as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead match:

```
^(?!.*[+*-]{2})\S+
```

- `(?!.*[+*-]{2})` is negative lookahead to fail the match if 2 adjacent symbols appear in input anywhere.
- Use above in `MULTILINE` mode if you're matching each input in separate lines.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFgPui/2)

In Java use:

```
final String regex = "^(?!.*[+*-]{2})\\S+";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

Comment: can you please explain why you used \S instead of dot (.)? Because in my case, a text can also contain spaces.  Thus, I used ^(?!.*[+*-]{2}).+

Comment: ok, in that case you can use `^(?!.*[+*-]{2}).+` I just used `\S` since I didn't see any space in your input.